# AngularJs + Soket.Io - Socket initialization

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I have successfully implemented the chatroom in angularjs using node + socket.io

But hope you guys can help me, I am stuck in a situation where I listen to the socket on the clientside

```
socket.on('new message', function(data){
     $scope.messages.push(data);//then run ng-repeat in the template
});
```

Problem is,

1) if I put the above method inside the controller, the above get reinitialized(multiple listener binds) whenever I open that page again and again(We have multi page app)

or

2) if I put the above method (as the docs says) at a global place I lose the scope of the controller so I cant bind the latest model to the template

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

You could try disconnecting the socket when the `$scope` is destroyed...

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    socket.disconnect();
});
```

But I like the service based approach...

```
var SocketService = function(){
    var _messages = [];

    socket = connectMeToSomeSocket();

    socket.on('new message', function(data){
       _messages.push(data);
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'messages', {
        get: function(){
           return _messages;
        }
    })
};
```

Then inject the `socketService` in your controllers...

```
angular.controller('SomeCtrl',['$scope', 'socketService', function($scope, socketService){
   $scope.socket = socketService;
}])
```

And use `socket.messages` in your template...

```
 <li ng-repeat="msg in socket.messages">
```

If you don't like giving your templates access to the `socketService` or you don't like `Object.defineProperty`, then you can add a `bindScope` method your service...

```
 this.bindScope = function($scope){
   var stopWatching = $scope.$watchCollection(function(){ return _messages;}, function(){
         $scope.messages = _messages;
    });
   // may not be necessary as `Scope` prob cleans up after itself
   $scope.$on('$destroy', stopWatching);
 };
```

And use it in your controllers...

```
socketService.bindScope($scope);
```